# ORACLE add new column which base on other records from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

Hi so i have table called products, i have some information there like name,netto price,tax etc. I want to add new records named brutto_price which is automatically calculated as (netto_price + netto_price*tax) or (netto_price *1.22 if tax is null) its not allowed to insert null into netto_price. (tax could be null).
Im doing sth like this

```
alter table products add (brutto_price FLOAT DEFAULT netto_price*1.22 )

    UPDATE products
   SET brutto_price = netto_price + netto_price*tax
   where
   tax is not null;
```

but first query is not working (probably because i use record name in this) any idea?

Comment: What does `automatically calculated as (netto_price + netto_price*tax)` actually mean here, and can you include some data which explains this?

Comment: i mean, is it possible to insert only netto_price and tax and brutto_price will calculate by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` for the "if tax is null" bit:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  netto_price NUMBER,
  tax         NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO products (netto_price, tax) VALUES (10, 5.2);
INSERT INTO products (netto_price, tax) VALUES (20, NULL);

SELECT netto_price, tax,
       CASE WHEN tax IS NULL THEN netto_price * 1.22
            ELSE netto_price + netto_price * tax
            END as brutto_price
  FROM products;

NETTO_PRICE  TAX   BRUTTO_PRICE
   10        5,2           15,2
   20        NULL          24,4
```

Alternatively, there is a function called `NVL` that supplies a default value in case the argument is NULL:

```
SELECT netto_price, tax,
       netto_price * (1 + NVL(tax, 0.22)) AS brutto_price
  FROM products;
```

Maybe you don't need to add the brutto price as a real column (because you are then responsible to keep it up to date in case the netto_price or the tax change). Please have a look at "virtual columns":

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD (
  brutto_price NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    netto_price * (1 + NVL(tax, 0.22)))
);
```

Now you can select from your table and always get the right brutto_price computed:

```
SELECT * FROM products;

NETTO_PRICE  TAX   BRUTTO_PRICE
   10        5,2           15,2
   20        NULL          24,4
```

Even if you change the tax, the brutto_price changes automatically.

Comment: Very good, glad to help! Please note that not all tools are aware of such virtual columns. You obviously cannot INSERT into a column or UPDATE it etc. But you can build indexes on it, which is quite cool. Please note also @Gordon's remark on the datatype, NUMBER is better for currency than FLOAT.

Comment: i see, i will remember it

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is:

```
alter table products add brutto_price FLOAT;

update products
     set brutto_price = netto_price + netto_price * coalesce(tax, 0.22);
```

However, Oracle can simplify this logic by using [virtual columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1):

```
alter table products add brutto_price float as (netto_price + netto_price * coalesce(tax, 0.22));
```

No update is needed.  The value is always up-to-date.

Note:  `float` is a really bad choice for monetary values.  You should be using fixed point representations -- `number`/`numeric`/`decimal` instead.

Comment: i dont know why but:
but alter table products add brutto_price FLOAT DEFAULT netto_price*1.22;
its not working for me, error is saying:
column not allowed here

Comment: @Eldragon01 . . . Of course not.  I just copied that line from your question.  DEFAULT values can't refer to other columns.  You should really use the computed column.